# What is the difference between "in the extent that" and "in the extent to which"?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

So, if you replace "in the extent to which" by "in the extent that" in the following sentence, will it mean the same thing?

There is a limitation **in the extent to which** Sarah can distance herself from the ongoing protests.

Also thinking about "to the extent". Which one of the two does it match in terms of meaning?

Answer (score 1):

I've never come across "in the extent" at all and [google's Ngram viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=to+the+extent%2C+in+the+extent&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cto%20the%20extent%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cin%20the%20extent%3B%2Cc0) suggests that its use is extremely rare in publication compared to "to the extent that". I would also suggest that most of the recorded occurrences are in physically descriptive phrases like "... in the extent of the grounds ..." and not in the abstract, figurative or metaphorical use represented by your example.

Not only is "in the extent" rare it is illogical when it's used as you have done in your example. When you are talking about limits you are talking about the extremes of the scope for action: "...in the extent..." or, perhaps, "...within the extent..." would relate to the whole logical space defined by that extent, not just the boundaries of it.

I wouldn't use "in the extent" at all in the way you have done and would regard any use of it in that way that you come across as an error.